# setInterval() still triggering after clearInterval() in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following code setting and clearing an interval inside a NodeJS script.

Starting interval works fine, but when trying to clear it, the `stopping interval` console will trigger, but the interval will continue firing every minute.

```
app.get("/api", async (req, res) => {

    active = req.query.active;
    
    let interval = null;

    if (active == "true") {

        console.log("starting interval");

        interval = setInterval(async function() {
            try {
                const Posts = await getPosts();
                const Comments = await getComments();
                sendPosts().then(() => sendComments());

            } catch (e) {
                throw e;
            };
        }, 60000);

        res.json({ reddit: subreddit, discordChannel: discordChannel, activated: true});

    } else {

        console.log("stopping interval");

        clearInterval(interval);
        interval = null;

        res.json({ reddit: subreddit, discordChannel: discordChannel, activated: false});
    }
    
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `interval` variable is declared inside the route handler. Every time the route is called, a new `interval` variable is created. Reassigning that variable inside one invocation of the route does not change its value during other invocations of the route. You need:

```
let interval = null;
app.get("/api", async (req, res) => {
    // ...
```

You should also catch errors properly - your current approach will result in unhandled rejections here:

```
    interval = setInterval(async function() {
        try {
            const Posts = await getPosts();
            const Comments = await getComments();
            sendPosts().then(() => sendComments());

        } catch (e) {
            throw e;
        };
    }, 60000);
```

Only `throw` if there's something that can handle it up the call stack - if not, you should do whatever you reasonably can with the error *at that point* and stop without throwing.

Comment: @ericmitjans - But, several warnings with this code.  Calling the `/api` more than once with `active` true will overwrite the previous `interval` variable and then there will be no way to ever stop the prior interval timer.  And, this interval variable is one per server, not one per user so different users trying to do different things will conflict with each other.  Though you've accepted this answer, this is probably not the right implementation unless this is a single user server and that single user never makes mistakes.

Comment: i think a better approach is using hashmap assign each user or ipaddress as a key and interval as value.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move "let interval" outside of the call to app.get().

Right now the variable is declared inside the closure of the function which means it gets initialized every time a request comes in.

If it's outside the function, the variable becomes part of the global scope and its value will be remembered between requests.